# Как исправить ошибку в java?

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, drawable

написал код который должен по рандому ставить фотографию, если этот рандом выбрал g1 то он должен поставить файл g1.png.
Вот код:

```
package com.culturehappyhour.bluearcher.plug;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.culturehappyhour.bluearcher.R;

public class FinalScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView girl_photo;

    String[] photos = new String[]{
            "g1_c",
            "g2_c",
            "g3_c",
            "g4_c",
            "g5_c",
            "g6_c",
            "g7_c",
            "g8_c",
            "g9_c",
            "g10_c",
            "g11_c",
    };

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        int n = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * photos.length);
        System.out.println(photos[n]);
        if (photos[n].equals("g1_c")){
            girl_photo.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.g1);
        }
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_final_screen);

        girl_photo = findViewById(R.id.girlfriend);

    }
}
```

А вот ошибка которую я получаю:

```
error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Drawable
            girl_photo.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.g1);
```

Как это решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо:

```
girl_photo.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.g1);
```

используйте:

```
girl_photo.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.g1));
```

Answer (score 3):

Нужно поменять setImageDrawable на setImageResource